# NW.js icons (generally, and in Windows 10)

Tags: nw.js

Has anyone succeeded in replacing default NW.js logos -- either with the "icon": "string with path to icon" in the manifest OR with Resource Hacker?

After producing standalone .exe files (with Enigma Virtualbox)which work fine,  Resource Hacker seems to work, but the new .exe file produced will no longer run in Windows 10 -- yielding a "This program will not run on your PC..." error message.